# How do I read Athena-created Parquet tables into python

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I created a table using Athena CTAS statements.  Per Glue, I see that the table is stored on my s3 bucket.  I further confirmed that there are files in the expected place in my s3 bucket.

These files, however, are not parquet files (they are extension-less).  When I try to read them into python using `pd.read_parquet`, I get the Error "Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.".  A similar error occurs when I try to query the table and read the csv output using `pd.read_csv`.  There, the error is "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 0: invalid continuation byte".  I tried using awswrangler and got the same errors.

I'm pretty sure these errors are related to the SSE_S3 encryption I put on the bucket.  However, I'm at a loss as to how I can actually interact with these files outside of Athena.

Comment: Have you tried AWS Data wrangler https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stubs/awswrangler.s3.read_parquet.html ?

Comment: I did and got the same result.  However, I've since solved the issue, the problem was that the default athena workgroup had additional encryption

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is that the default Athena workgroup had CSE_KMS encryption turned on.  I couldn't quickly figure out how to pass these options via `awswrangler`, so I took the shortcut of recreating the table using another workgroup that didn't have encryption.